# Use a pointer to switch between two other pointers in Qt Creator Ui

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qt-creator

i do have two Labels in my applications. They are both in each tab. Now i want to witch between those labels by using an pointer that switchs between those labels when tab was changed.

my ui_mainwindow.h defines:

```
    ProLabel *imageLabel;
    ProLabel *imageLabel_1;
    ProLabel *imageLabel_2;
```

but only imageLabel_1 and imageLabel_2 are shown in the GUI. I added a third Label (imageLabel) to use it as a variable to switch between the Labels (1/2). So I wrote follwing code in a slot which proves tab changed. So if tab is changed, the other imageLabel_1/2 (pointer) should be used in the hole code, when it says: imageLabel.

my slot when tab changed:

```
 if(tab == 0)
 {
     this->ui->imageLabel = this->ui->imageLabel_1;
 }
 else{
    this->ui->imageLabel = this->ui->imageLabel_2;
 }
```

I also set the imageLabel_1 whe MainWindow is created. The Window disapear like normal. But if I try to load an image (than it should display the image in the **imageLabel**) it crashes.

Don't know if it was understandable. Does anybody has an idea if i can handle the pointers like that.. or how to do it different?

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest to exchange rather the label's content than the labels.

Comment: but the 2 labels are displayed in the two different tabs. and i don't know how to manage that all the functions i wrote also work in the tab 2... without writing all the code twice for every tab :/

Comment: You don't need to duplicate your code. You can simply do: `this->ui->imageLabel->setText(this->ui->imageLabel_1->text());`. The same for images.

Comment: don't know if i get it right. at the end i will only show imageLabel and imageLabel_1 and iamgeLabel_2 are invisible, only to store different data (image) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simpler ways: 1) Change the label contents, either the image or the text it contains, or 2) set the label to hidden with `ui->label2->isVisible(false)`.

Comment: so that i have 2 tabs but one label. (not 1 label for each tab like i have it right now) ? how is it possible to show the same label in 2 tabs? :)

Comment: @PixelBanana: think of each tab as it's own unique area, it should usually contain it's own unique elements, this creates a level of separation so changes to one won't affect the other by accident. So each tab should have it's own child label.

Comment: okay, i already have two labels. one in tab1 and one in tab2. i implemented a button that loads an image in tab1 (label1). but the button don't work for tab2 (label2). and because i wrote label1 in lots of different locations in code (other buttons etc.) i want to use a variable-like thing which i can overwrite with label2/label1. so i don't have to care in all other locations in code.. is clear what i mean? :)  (EDIT: i wrote only label1 in my code.. label2 is missing)

Comment: That's starting to make more sense now. Rather than using `this->ui->imageLabel` which will go wrong you need to add `ProLabel *m_label;` in your `.h`, then in your `.cpp` do `m_label = new ProLabel` to create it. You can then associate the `ui->imageLabel*` pointers to it and use the `m_label` instead.

Comment: Oh yeees! It works! Thank you so much! You saved my day and my bachelor thesis program! my deadline is tomorrow :D Thank you very very much!

Comment: You're welcome, just so you know the why does it work, when you use the `this->ui` notation it uses the `ui` namespace that Qt Creator generates, so the element you're referring to is a UI element in the designed UI, not just a bare pointer. So you were assigning a ui pointer to a ui pointer, which as you found out doesn't do a lot.